# REACT component is sticking to page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a single page application that has a homepage and two other pages. The issue is that the homepage doesn't "disappear" when I click the links with react-router - the new components are just rendered underneath the existing component[See component rendered beneath the other component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPOrR.jpg).

The two linked components work as expected - they replace one or the other when the appropriate link is clicked on. But 1) they create whitespace before they're even rendered 2) they don't "replace" the home component.

How do I "hide" the home component when I switch pages? Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Basics from './Basics';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Home';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={Home}></Route>
      <Route path="/basics" component={Basics}></Route>
      <Route path="/flies" component={Flies}></Route>
    </div>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: Hi @yoursweater did you get any answer for this?

Comment: @AzySır Yes, you can use <Switch> or <Route exact path>. See below

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 solutions for this.

Change your `/` to be `exact`, like so

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

or, move the `/` `Route` to be the last in the list

```
<Route path="/basics" component={Basics} />
<Route path="/flies" component={Flies} />
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

These `Route`s should be inside a `Switch` component, available from `react-router`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think that those fixes are redundant when combined with `<Switch>`, however, because it renders a `<Route>` _exclusively_. So, you avoid the problem of sticky components that you want to disappear when you render a different one.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. Apparently replacing the `<div>` in the `<Router>` with `<Switch>` allows each component to be rendered exclusively, one at a time.

```
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Home}></Route>
      <Route path="/basics" component={Basics}></Route>
      <Route path="/flies" component={Flies}></Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> A `<Switch>` component looks through its children `<Route>`s and
> renders the first one that matches the current URL.

If you've multiple routes(which renders an *anchor* tag under the hood), then you have to use `<Switch>` to render one of them that matches according to the algorithm, in case of **React-router** it renders first one that matches the current URL the most.

You can look at this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start